# Creating a relative path to a Database in Asp.net for a library

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, relative-path

In school I am part of a team of four working to create a GUI to translate the paper records of a made-up company and their functionality to a digital format.  We're using an ASP.NET website for this purpose.

Basically we use stored procedures and C# classes to represent the database.  The folder we're using for the project contains the site and the libraries in separate folders.  If I try to open the site from the folder containing both these elements the site will not run.  I want to know if there is some way I can set up a relative path to the database in the Settings.Settings.cs file (or by some other means) of my libraries so I don't have to constantly change the database location for the connection string value every time we move the project.

I suppose I should also mention that the database is in an App_Data folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your database is in App_Data folder, you should use a connection string like this in web.config:

```
<add name="Database1ConnectionString1" 
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

`|DataDirectory|` will refer to App_Data, wherever you install your web app.

Comment: That is how I have my connection string set up.  It doesn't do me any good for finding the database from the libraries though (which are in different folders from the site).

Comment: In what kind of application do you use those libraries? If they run in an ASP.NET app, they'll be alright. If you're using those libraries in a Console or Windows app, then it have to be made in a different way.

Comment: I must've been looking at the wrong file or something.  I ended up changing it like you had there and it seems to be working perfectly. I think the initial problem was that I was trying to change the path in the settings file and either it didn't like the pipes or I missed the removal of a quote so it wouldn't accept it.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Server.MapPath(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the
>   corresponding physical directory on the server.

Comment: Where would I add this method?